# Robolectric in library module: manifest merger fails due to placeholder not being provided

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin, robolectric

I'm trying to use Robolectric in a library module. The library expects the app module to specify a value for a manifest placeholder. When I run the test I get an error:

`Attribute data@scheme at tempFile1ProcessTestManifest273304251747743144.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <someParameter> is provided.`

As a result, the test isn't run.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, we need to provide Robolectric a fake AndroidManifest.xml that either defines this placeholder or completely removes the node that requires it.

An example fake AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <application>
    <activity
      android:name="com.example.RedirectActivity"
      tools:node="remove" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

In the example above, I chose to remove the node that requires the placeholder altogether.

Then the correct place to put this AndroidManifest.xml is in the root of the `test` directory of the library module. For example: `/library/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml`.

With this setup, the placeholder issue is now gone.